# Cannot change nodejs version using n

Tags: node.js, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, n

I'm working with raspbian ver 8. I have a preinstalled version of node running (ver 5.0.0). I'm trying to downgrade it to 4.6.1 using n. However, i'm getting the following error after a long wait

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo n 4.6.1

```
 install : node-v4.6.1
```

Error: invalid version 4.6.1

Can anyone provide the root cause of this along with the possible fix?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, remove current node js.

Then download the version code, then build and install.

I also face this problem earlier, in my case, build from source code solve the problem.